# How to pass System.Type in ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I want to bind a function with a parameter to a TextBlock in XAML. The function parameter has the type `System.Type`. How do I notate a complex object as MethodParameter in XAML?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyKey" ObjectType="{x:Type MyType}" MethodName="MyMethod">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <System:Int32>123</System:Int32> <!-- e.g. a primitive type parameter -->
            <MyNamespace:MyCustomType>WHAT COMES HERE?</MyNamespace:MyCustomType>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
[...]
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyKey}}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `x:Type`:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyKey" ObjectType="{x:Type MyType}" MethodName="MyMethod">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <System:Int32>123</System:Int32>
        <x:Type TypeName="MyNamespace:MyCustomType"></x:Type>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.Type` is an abstract class, so you cannot pass an argument of type `System.Type`.

Instead you can pass a `string` and get the corresponding `Type` using `Type.GetType()`.

Eg;

```
   <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MyKey" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Class1}" MethodName="Fun">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <sys:String>System.Double</sys:String>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>

public class Class1
{
    public string Fun(string typename)
    {
        Type type = Type.GetType(typename);
        return type.ToString();
    }
}
```